# issue with rewrite url blog.php to blogs

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this so far, it works but when I use it as

http://www.example.com/blogs

it redirects to

http://www.example.com/blog.php

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex website-design-example.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs$ blog.php      [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/$ blog.php     [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/page/([0-9]+)$ /blog.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/([0-9]+)$ /blogPost.php?post=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-=\/]+)$ /blogPost.php?post=$1 [NC,L]
```

Can someone please guide me what am I doing wrong!

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: it actually somehow redirecting to http://www.example.com/blog.php when I go to http://www.example.com/blogs for the very first attempt and I couldn't find out why! Afterwards it works great. But I fail to understand why it redirects in the first attempt!